Diagnosing tripped breaker on the dishwasher circuit?
Our dishwasher trips the breaker every time, mid-cycle, and I'm having trouble diagnosing the issue with my limited electrical knowledge. Here are some facts/observations that I hope are relevant:

The dishwasher does not trip the breaker when the heating element is disconnected, but I've replaced the element to no avail
I've opened the dishwasher up and inspected the wiring half a dozen times, but found no evidence of water leaks, corrosion, exposed wire, etc.
The dishwasher is on a 15A circuit with the garbage disposal. The dishwasher still trips the circuit with the garbage disposal unplugged.
The dishwasher is plugged into a GFCI outlet (2-gang/2-duplex/4 outlets total). When these issues began, it was actually the GFCI outlet that would trip. However, eventually (let's say after ~10 GFCI trips), the circuit breaker began tripping instead of the GFCI outlet, and now it's the breaker that trips every time.
The breaker is a 15A Siemens QAF 2-pole AFCI. When the breaker is flipped back on, the arc fault indicator is illuminated.
The current draw of the dishwasher at the outlet never exceeds 8A (measured with clamp meter).
The dishwasher works fine when plugged into another outlet/circuit (non-GFCI outlet w/AFCI breaker, if it matters). We've been running it via extension cord for 3 months with no issues.
I've tested the GFCI outlet with an outlet tester and it passes

My inclination is to replace the breaker, and hope that there is not a wiring issue somewhere in the circuit. Are there any other steps I can take here to refine the diagnosis? Any likely root causes that I should consider?

probably the dishwasher is leaking water onto the wires

Sorry, I omitted some things from my notes as I had tossed out the idea of the dishwasher being the problem a while ago, perhaps prematurely. Originally, I thought the problem may be the heating element, as the dishwasher does not cause the breaker to trip when the heating element is disconnected, but the element doesn't seem to be faulty (I replaced it just to make sure). I had also opened up the dishwasher multiple times and checked all the wiring and didn't notice any signs of water, corrosion, exposed wire, etc. Sounds like I may need a professional diagnosis.

Try running a space heater on the affected circuit.

you might have a defective wall plug

I am not sure a clamp meter will reliably tell you the "draw" of a dishwasher - several parts cycle off and on. A 15A circuit should adequately power this type of appliance. Additionally, I agree with others that something internally has shorted to ground - and it may be a component like the pump or more likely the heating element which is either wet or melted. And for a split second, your ampere rating goes haywire before the circuit trips. The fact that you don't measure unbridled current rushing through a shorted appliance testifies to the value of electrical code.

It's certainly worth replacing the wall outlet and inspecting the wiring in the box. Do you know what else is on that circuit?

I had a similar issue with a hot water tank.
It would work fine for weeks , sometime months.  Then trip the breaker.
The issue was a poor connection of wires at a wire nut. The poor connection caused excess resistance. The resistance caused the plastic to melt on the wire nut.
Check every wire connection before condemning the dishwasher.

Good call, it would be intermittent because the vibration of the washer would cause the loose connection to fail.

As Jansen said in the comments, it seems much more likely that the breaker is telling you the dishwasher is unsafe and needs repair, than that the breaker has gone bad. Especially since the GFCI was telling you the same thing in its own way,
Sorry, but it's time to have the dishwasher serviced or replaced.

Interesting, I was assuming that the dishwasher was not the issue as it has worked without any problems on another 15A circuit with an AFCI breaker. Worth testing on a different GFCI outlet on a different circuit, maybe?

@Nick, the symptoms you describe are consistent with a weak arc-to-ground fault: it only takes a few milliamps of leakage current to trigger a GFCI, and the AFCI is looking for a specific pattern of electrical noise on the line.  The dishwasher will keep running fine until it becomes a strong arc-to-ground fault, at which point you'd better hope it triggers the breaker's overcurrent protection before catching fire.


When the breaker is flipped back on, the arc fault indicator is illuminated.

Arc faults frequently turn into fire hazards.  Somewhere, you have electricity jumping between two conductors that should be insulated from each other. This can be hard to diagnose visually since it can occur between extremely tiny exposed bits of wiring.  You'll probably want to get an electrician to look at it.
One thing you can do is to locate the outlet that the dishwasher is connected to.  Unplug the cables, turn off the breaker, and remove the outlet's faceplate.  Take the outlet out of the wall box and carefully inspect all the wire connections to the outlet.  Many times these outlets are indirectly exposed to moisture in places like a cabinet under the sink, and over time wires can oxidize, degrade, or work loose.  Neither the outlet nor the wiring should show any signs of damage.  The wiring should be securely connected to the screw terminals on the side of the outlet, not the "backstab" connectors on the rear.  Your live and neutral wires should not have more insulation stripped than what is needed to make a solid connection.  If anything inside that wall box looks damaged or loose, I'd replace the outlet and/or cut the damaged part off the wiring and re-strip/re-connect it.  If there are any connections made inside the wall box using wire nuts, double-check that they're still nice and tight.

It's possible that it's not the dishwasher itself that's causing the issue. Since the dishwasher doesn't have a dedicated circuit, your dishwasher may be running when another appliance or countertop device is running, so it could simply be drawing too much power for multiple devices.
This can go into the age of the devices/appliances. The older something gets, the more power it draws. You've already replaced the heating element, so maybe there's something else that needs replaced, like a toaster. Or maybe your fridge is kicking in during a wash cycle and the compressor is drawing too much power while the heating element is on. This is more likely to happen with older fridges, since newer ones try to reduce the compressor start spike.
You've measured 8A at the dishwasher, but what else is drawing power? What's the power draw at the circuit breaker, or even the GFCI that keep tripping? Is your meter capable of measuring and displaying sub-second spikes?
And an extension cord may be reducing the current draw because of it's length, wire gauge, age, or even if it's left partially coiled. If the cord is warm to the touch during or after use, then you have major issues and need to stop using the extension cord, not that you should be using it anyway. (I had to use an extension cord for a whole house water heater once, so I know circumstances sometimes dictate uses other than what's recommended.)
Similar to what kelsham's answer states, it's probably time to have some service done by a licensed, insured, and bonded professional. An electrician should be able to narrow it down to just one device, and an appliance tech should be able to fix the device. And, of course, there's always the option for replacement.
Or...
Maybe the water pump in the dishwasher is causing a power spike. Since you've tried it without the heating element, the pump is the only other thing that would be drawing a significant amount of power. Now that I've been proofreading this answer, this seems like the most likely possibility. I haven't worked on dishwashers, so IDK how hard it is to replace that pump. You may still need a service tech to replace that, but maybe not.
The water pump might just be (partially) clogged and having to do more work to get water through it, causing a power spike. Try cleaning out the pipes first, then see if there's still an issue, and then it might be the pump dying. This might be expensive enough of a part that you want the opinion of a service tech if you want to risk replacing the pump or just replace the whole appliance.

The description of the problem points to a ground-fault and/or arc-fault issue, not overcurrent. Which may indeed be related to other items on the circuit, or may be the dishwasher itself, or may be wiring problems. But it isn't overcurrent.

@MichaelHarvey, yes. https://www.palmerelectric.com/problems-of-aging-electrical-systems and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/563944/is-the-performance-of-electronic-devices-affected-by-their-age. Not to mention that heat damage cause by simply using some devices will cause the components to heat more, and hotter devices are less efficient. https://www.apollodisplays.com/blog/how-high-temperatures-can-affect-your-electronics/

@MichaelHarvey, speaking as a former computer tech, computer PSUs definitely lose efficiency over time. I can't find any study done on the effects, but there's plenty of people in the industry that see and talk about the effects. https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/the-age-of-a-psu-doesnt-alter-the-performance-does-it.531691/ and https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-that-my-PSU-has-gotten-weaker-over-time-with-playing-video-games-Prebuilt-PC-with-500w-PSU The harder your PSU has to work to provide the same power, the less efficient it is. Even the efficiency ratings on PSUs prove that.
